# How do I color fill this EMA Chart

Tags: pine-script

When the crossover between EMA25 and EMA50 happens, I would like to fill in the empty space with a red and green that is see-through.

I know I can use `fill()`, but I am just not sure how.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay=true)

EMA25 = ema(close, 25)
EMA50 = ema(close, 50)

bull_cross = crossover( EMA25, EMA50)
bear_cross = crossover( EMA50, EMA25)


plot(EMA25, title="EMA(25)", color=color.orange, linewidth=9 )
plot(EMA50, title="EMA(50)", color=color.purple, linewidth=9 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
//@version=4 
strategy("EMA Shadow", overlay=true)

EMA25 = ema(close, 25) 
EMA50 = ema(close, 50)

bull_cross = crossover( EMA25, EMA50) 
bear_cross = crossover( EMA50, EMA25)

a = plot(EMA25, title="EMA(25)", color=color.orange, linewidth=9 ) 
b = plot(EMA50, title="EMA(50)", color=color.purple, linewidth=9 )

var color col = na
col := EMA25 > EMA50 ? color.green : color.red
fill(a,b,color=col,transp=40)
```

The trick is to assign your plots for both EMAs to a variable and use those variables in the fill() function.